# what does this illegal expression mean in pascal?

Tags: pascal

this is the code and I get these two errors 1: 8,14 illegal expression and 2: 8,1 ''warning: variable k does not seem to be initialized

```
program komunaluri_1;
var 
  den, g, w, das, k : integer;
begin
  den := 21;
  g := 50;
  w := 340;  
  das := 250;
  k = w + g + den + das;               
  write('your total is'); write(k);
end.
```

i was trying to add all those numbers and then write the total but i cant seem to fix any of these errors

Comment: `k=` ----> `k:=`

Answer (score 5):

Your expression `k = w + g + den + das` is a test to determine if `k` is equal to `w + g + den + das` rather than an *assignment* of that *to* `k`, which is almost certainly what you wanted.

```
program komunaluri_1;
var 
  den, g, w, das, k : integer;
begin
  den := 21;
  g := 50;
  w := 340;  
  das := 250;
  k := w + g + den + das;               
  write('your total is'); write(k);
end.
```

Consider this very simple program:

```
program test;
begin
  4 * 3
end.
```

It will give the same error because it also features a pointless expression.

```
Free Pascal Compiler version 3.2.2 [2023/09/18] for x86_64
Copyright (c) 1993-2021 by Florian Klaempfl and others
Target OS: Darwin for x86_64
Compiling test.pas
test.pas(4,1) Error: Illegal expression
test.pas(5) Fatal: There were 1 errors compiling module, stopping
Fatal: Compilation aborted
Error: /usr/local/bin/ppcx64 returned an error exitcode
```